# Javascript jQuery calling on API to fill table but receiving undefined for a particular object call

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, discogs-api

So the problem I seem to be having is that when I populate my table the object *discogsObjects.year* populates my table consistently with "undefined" despite the fact that when I call it in devtools it returns values of years called from the API. My format is consistent with the code so I'm not sure what the problem could be...

Thank you!

```
var discogsObjects = {
    title: [],
    label: [],
    year: [],
};


$(".artistform").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var band = ($("#userInput").val());
  var url = "https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=" + band + "&key=olnzRAzKsxiVlgocWNCH&secret=RPCwqvPXDmFkHHNzDePPKIcMsHRmNUIK"

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: (data)=> {
      console.log(data.results);



      for (i = 0; i<21; i++) {
        for(var key in data.results[i]){
          //if (key === "id") idArr.push(data.results[i][key]);
          if (key === "title")  discogsObjects.title.push(data.results[i][key]);
          if (key === "label") discogsObjects.label.push(data.results[i][key]);
          if (key === "year") discogsObjects.year.push(data.results[i][key]);
        }

          //$thead(.hidden).show()
          // $('#resultsHead').append('<tr><td>Year of Release</td><td>Artist Release</td><td>Record Label</td></tr>');

         $('#resultsTable').append('<tr><td>'+discogsObjects.title[i]+'</td><td>'+discogsObjects.year[i]+'</td><td>'+discogsObjects.label[0]+'</td></tr>');


      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: is there a reason why you have to push the data to discogsObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first object returned in the "results" array is a description of the band which does not have a `year` attribute so the first iteration of your for loop doesn't populate the `year` array in the `discogsObjects` object and thus on every iteration thereafter `undefined` will be appended to the DOM because it's off by one.

For example, using "Maroon 5" the first object returned will be:

```
{  
    "thumb":"https://api-img.discogs.com/gcuqJ3Ni4_2F_F_35xU7anju50Q=/150x150/smart/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(40)/discogs-images/A-192151-1452146008-4372.jpeg.jpg",
    "title":"Maroon 5",
    "uri":"/artist/192151-Maroon-5",
    "resource_url":"https://api.discogs.com/artists/192151",
    "type":"artist",
    "id":192151
}
```

So your for loop won't find a key named "year", and `discogsObject.year` will be empty. Then you append `discogsObject.year[i]` when `i = 0` which is `undefined`. Next, i is incremented and a year is found in the next object, pushing it onto the year array, but when appending it to the DOM you're trying to do `discogsObject.year[i]` when `i = 1`, but `discogsObject.year.length = 1` so this is `undefined`.